# Parse.com cloud httpRequest response.text does not convert to JavaScript object

Tags: json, parse-platform, es6-promise

I have a http request I am trying to make on an afterSave method in my Cloud Code. I have been able to create my request, and when I `console.log(response)` it outputs a block that contains the information that I am after. I am aware that response.text is a string so I am trying to run JSON.parse(response.text) so I can access my API response.

I can print out what appears to be an object after running JSON.parse, but much of the data within my response is stripped out. I know it is not the fault of the API because I have another function that runs on the client with the same query and it works correctly.

What is the correct way to parse the response.text from a Parse.Cloud.httpRequest to maintain my data.

Comment: try like this var result = response.toJSON().text;

Comment: Thank you, the response is a JSON object, so this method failed. I also tried response.text.toJSON() which again stripped out the data I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var result = JSON.parse(response['text'])`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It still strips out the inner data.